# How can I suppress reports with $0 totals?

Tags: ms-access, report

I've inherited an Access report that gathers individual invoices and payments, displays all the details, and the report calculates a total.  Is there a report event where I can suppress the invoices that have an exactly $0 total?  Or do I need to build an aggregate query to eliminate customers before the calculations in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find it easier to do this prior to generating the report rather than trying to place the logic in the report itself. I've never been a fan of "complex rules" being embedded within a report. Too often you find yourself having to alter the rule after the fact and maintenance can be a real headache.

Comment: I'll agree with you in theory, and if I'd built the report from scratch I wouldn't build it that way, precisely as you say, now I need to alter the rule and maintenance is a headache.